# Time Speed Control for Scene Animation

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, video

Need to slow down the video when a glass piece seen on camera. But i cant do it with rigid body speed cause of baking for solution for the parts animation. How can i animate the speed of everything that animated on their normal speed. I cant do it on video sequencer or after effects etc... video needs to be 60fps and its not good for time stretch.

Comment: From what information we have, it sounds like there can be no soup, but it’s vague. Can you more clearly describe what is happening in the scene?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ive a scene with rigid body simulation. i just animate this scene with rigid body world speed but now i need to animate global time speed. Baked all simulation to animate pieces. if i edit the render in video sequence editor fps really down so its ruining the video how can i slow down all the world time with animation? like time remapping but need to animate it